# Change design on InAppBrowser for Cordova 2.3.0+/PhoneGap on iOS

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

We're using PhoneGap to package our web app on iOS and Android, and we're using the InAppBrowser plugin to display some external pages. We'd like to have this displayed in our own design, and not the default PhoneGap design.

For Android this was kind of easy, I just created my own plugin based on the Cordova one with my own layout - and that was it. On iOS, however, I'm at a loss at finding good resources for styling the InAppBrowser plugin. The layout is hard coded in the CDVInAppBrowser.m file, same as it was for the Android version. But I'm not very well versed in Objective-C.

How do I best manage to do this, are there any github projects or whatever that does this already?